# why does Parse cloud code save one object but not the other?

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse Cloud Code.. however I am trying something that theoretically should be straight forward and I cannot understand why it won't work!

in my User class i have an array of playableFriends, when i create a Game object I wish to remove the player and opponent from each others playableFriends Array

The code to remove the opponent from the players array works.. but for some reason unknown to me the code to remove the player from the opponents array does not.. even if it is the only code being run.

I have output the player and opponent objects to the console to ensure they exist and I have also tried using the fetch command on the opponent but that didn't work either

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Game",function(request, response){

  //return if existing game 
  if (request.object.existed()){
      return;
  }

  //get player
  var player = request.object.get("playerIdle");
  //get opponent
  var opponent = request.object.get("playerTurn");

  //remove opponent as playable friend
  player.remove("playableFriends", opponent);
  //remove player as opponents playable friend
  opponent.remove("playableFriends", player);

  player.save();
  opponent.save();
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

regards
Byron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the two save operations at the end of your functions are asynchronous. Basically, this means that when your `player.save();` is reached, the execution continues on to the next line even though your save operation may not have completed (in your case it seems that it's the second save that is not completed). There are a couple ways of overcoming this: callbacks and promises.

A callback is a block of code that is passed into your async function that will be executed when the function completes. A promise, on the other hand, allows you to be notified when an async function completes. With promises, you use the `then()` function to continue execution once the original promise is fulfilled, which can either be resolved if the async operation was successful, or rejected if the async operation returned an error.  Using promises, the last two lines of your function could be adapted as follows:

```
player.save().then( function(result){
    return opponent.save();
}, function (error){
    // We had an error saving the player
}).then( function(result){
    console.log("Successfully saved user and opponent");
}, function(error){
    // We had an error saving the opponent
});
```

I suggest you read up on both callbacks and promises as asynchronous functions are a fundamental part of working in the Parse Cloud Code environment. [This blog post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) would be a great place to start. Callbacks may be easier to understand in the short term, but may lead to code that is harder to understand and maintain as your application grows in complexity.

EDIT

Since the ACLs on your opponent user restrict write operations to only that user, you'll also need to use the master key when saving that objects.

Comment: Thanks Todd for the awesome response! I love Promises.. have done a lot of reading and implemented them as you recommended.. The problem still arises although now I was able to output the error message from the promise (error.message) and turns out it is failing because a session/token is required to alter the opponent.. UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use the master key to bypass the ACLs on the opponent. Try putting 'Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();' at the top of your function.

Comment: Parse only allows User objects to be changed by the logged in user.. I was able to use a master key to override this check. opponent.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });

Comment: yeah thanks Todd.. just researched that behaviour! I was able to tighten up the security by setting the useMasterKey variable to only apply to that call and not the whole function.. thanks again for your guidance